# Styling tabs component at Vaadin 14 based on state using custom css class

Tags: java, css, vaadin14

I am using Vaadin 14 and I am trying to style a tabs component butI got a little confused. I am setting a class name for my component because I don't want to change  the tabs style for all pages at my app, but I don't know how to combine this class name with states, e.g selected.
I have used this:

```
    [part="tabs"] ::slotted(vaadin-tab[selected]){
  background-color:white;
  color:#002641;
}
```

but it is global, so it affects all tabs components at my app.
I have also tried this code below, but it didn't make any difference.
**patient-tabs is the class name that I have set for the tabs component that I want to change.**

```
    :host(.patient-tabs)[part~="tabs"] ::slotted(vaadin-tab[selected]){
    background-color: red;
    color:#002641;
}
```

Comment: Can you also disclose how you are importing these styles using @CssImport, are you importing the style using themeFor parameter or without ?